# HttpClient.GetJsonAsync Not found. (blazor server)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have installed the package by adding the latest package ref.
from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient/
But still i am unable to find the desired function like .. `Client.GetJsonAsync`

*Can you please help me out if i am missing something?*
**Thanks**.

I am trying out here but cant.

```
public async Task<User> GetUser(string Id)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var user = await client.GetJsonAsync($"{BaseUrl}Get-User/{Id}");
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(user);
        }
```

Comment: You're probably using server-side Blazor, aren't you ? If so, you shouldn't use this package: Provides experimental support for using System.Text.Json with HttpClient. Intended for use with Blazor running under WebAssembly.............Use IHttpClientFactory instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature is the following:

```
public static async Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, string requestUri);
```

So it is a *generic* method and you will have to include the type argument in the call.

In your case, this should look like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var user = await client.GetJsonAsync<User>($"{BaseUrl}Get-User/{Id}");
```

This will already deserialize the JSON response to the `User` type.

Note that you will need a using for the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components` namespace in order for this extension method to appear.

Comment: @DiegoVenancio There is little reason to make HTTP calls from Blazor Server. All the logic runs on the server already, so if you want to hit the server API, just call it directly instead. By making a HTTP call, you would make a network roundtrip from the server to the same server for no real reason. Of course, if you need to call another API (different server), then you can still make a (server-side) HTTP call. You wouldn't use the client Blazor HTTP package then though.

Answer (score 8):

**1. Add nuget package `System.Net.Http.Json`**

**2. Add this namespace in using System.Net.Http.Json**

Nothing worked for me and nobody pointing at this clearly.

These extension methods exists in `System.Net.Http.Json` namespace.
To use these methods you need to first add this package [System.Net.Http.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Json).
Then add this `System.Net.Http.Json` namespace in using.
Only then json extension methods will appear with HttpClient object.

Comment: Method is now also called "GetFromJsonAsync". The amount of trouble this nonsense has caused me is shameful. But thanks for this as well, was a first step to resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're using Client Side blazor

These are extension method of HTTP Client, So you have to pass type with GetJsonAsync and method would return an object. This method will throw an error if your API would return blank response. For that case, you can use `httpClient.GetAsync` method

[image]

Comment: Aren't a good way post images instead code... Please, delete image e copy/paste codes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this namespace

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;
```

then change your code like shown below:

```
public async Task<User> GetUser(string Id)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    return await client.GetFromJsonAsync<User>($"{BaseUrl}Get-User/{Id}");   
}
```

Comment: You must to add package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components`